# ANTLR: simple example from ANTLRWorks wizard doesn't work

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, antlrworks

Grammar:

```
grammar test;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

STRING
    :  '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;

start 
    :   STRING EOF;
```

It is grammar generated with wizard; I added rule 'start'.

Input in interpreter:

```
"abc"
```

Result in console:

```
[19:09:54] Interpreting...
[19:09:54] problem matching token at 1:2 MismatchedTokenException(97!=34)
[19:09:54] problem matching token at 1:3 NoViableAltException('b'@[1:1: Tokens : ( WS | STRING );])
[19:09:54] problem matching token at 1:4 NoViableAltException('c'@[1:1: Tokens : ( WS | STRING );])
[19:09:54] problem matching token at 1:5 NoViableAltException(''@[()* loopback of 11:12: ( ESC_SEQ | ~ ( '\\' | '"' ) )*])
```

Screenshot:
http://habreffect.ru/files/200/4cac2487f/antlr.png

ANTLRWorks v1.4
Tried also from console with ANTLR v3.2, same result.

If I type "\nabc" instead of "abc", it works fine.
If I put ESC_SEQ on right in STRING rule, then "abc" works, but "\nabc" fails.

Comment: grammar test;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

STRING
    :  '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;

start 
 : STRING EOF;

Comment: I type "abc" in interpreter.

Console:

[19:09:44] Interpreting...
[19:09:54] Interpreting...
[19:09:54] problem matching token at 1:2 MismatchedTokenException(97!=34)
[19:09:54] problem matching token at 1:3 NoViableAltException('b'@[1:1: Tokens : ( WS | STRING );])
[19:09:54] problem matching token at 1:4 NoViableAltException('c'@[1:1: Tokens : ( WS | STRING );])
[19:09:54] problem matching token at 1:5 NoViableAltException(''@[()* loopback of 11:12: ( ESC_SEQ | ~ ( '\\' | '"' ) )*])

Comment: ANTLRWorks version: 1.4.
Same thing happens when I try to run interpreter with ANTLR 3.2 from console.

Comment: This bug has reappeared in ANTLRWorks 1.4.3.  Or was never fixed in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in ANTLRWorks 1.4. You could try with ATLRWorks 1.3 (or earlier), perhaps that version works properly (I did a quick check with v1.4 only!).

From the console, both your example strings (`"abc"` and `"\nabc"`) are being parsed without any problems. Here's my test-rig and the corresponding output:

```
grammar test;

start 
  :  STRING {System.out.println("parsed :: "+$STRING.text);} EOF
  ;

WS  
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;

STRING
  :  '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
  ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT 
  :  ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') 
  ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
  :  '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
  |  UNICODE_ESC
  |  OCTAL_ESC
  ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
  :  '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
  |  '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
  |  '\\' ('0'..'7')
  ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
  :  '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
  ;
```

Note that the grammar is the same as yours, only formatted a bit different.

And the "main" class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(args[0]);
        testLexer lexer = new testLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        testParser parser = new testParser(tokens);
        parser.start();
    }
}
```

Now from the console you create a parser and lexer:

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool test.g
```

Compile all .java source files:

```
javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java
```

and run the "main" class:

```
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Demo \"\\nabc\"
// output:                                   parsed :: "\nabc"

java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Demo \"abc\"
// output:                                   parsed :: "abc"
```

*(for Windows, replace the `:` with a `;` in the commands above)*

Note that the command line parameters above are examples run on Bash, where the `"` and `\` need to be escaped: this may be different on your system. But as you can see from the output: both `"\nabc"` and `"abc"` get parsed properly.

ANTLRWorks is a great tool for editing grammar files, but (in my experience) has quite a bit of such funny bugs in it. That's why I only edit the grammar(s) with it and generate, compile and test the files on the console as I showed you.

HTH